# Angular Schematics generate with interactive user interaction

Tags: javascript, angular, code-generation, angular-schematics

I have a simple situation:

- I want to run schematics
- read the project tree
- find special files (according to the special rule)
- List them to the console
- Retrieve some user interruption (select some file from the list, ask the user for desicion)
- Finish the schematics according to the user input.

How I can implement it?
Thanks for you support!

Comment: Can you share something that you tries so far?

Comment: Honestly - i did now found any information about it. Is it possible?